# HoloEverywhere: BaseExpandableListAdapter getChildView and Checkbox state

Tags: android, android-layout, android-holo-everywhere

I'm using Holoeverywhere library and corresponding classes: `ExpandableListview`,  `BaseExpandableListAdapter`.

`getChildView` of a class extending `BaseExpandableListAdapter` I have contains:

```
    checkBox.setText(option.getTitle());
    checkBox.setChecked(true);
```

When a `checkBox` element is rendered, text is set properly but it's state remains unchecked. Why isn't it checked?

A sample adapter:

```
/**
 * A simple adapter which maintains an ArrayList of photo resource Ids.
 * Each photo is displayed as an image. This adapter supports clearing the
 * list of photos and adding a new photo.
 *
 */
public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    // Sample data set.  children[i] contains the children (String[]) for groups[i].
    private String[] groups = { "People Names", "Dog Names", "Cat Names", "Fish Names" };
    private String[][] children = {
            { "Arnold", "Barry", "Chuck", "David" },
            { "Ace", "Bandit", "Cha-Cha", "Deuce" },
            { "Fluffy", "Snuggles" },
            { "Goldy", "Bubbles" }
    };

    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return children[groupPosition][childPosition];
    }

    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return children[groupPosition].length;
    }

    public android.widget.TextView getGenericView() {
        // Layout parameters for the ExpandableListView
        AbsListView.LayoutParams lp = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 64);

        TextView textView = new TextView(TestActivity.this);
        textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        // Center the text vertically
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT);
        // Set the text starting position
        textView.setPadding(36, 0, 0, 0);
        return textView;
    }

    public CheckBox getCheckbox() {
        // Layout parameters for the ExpandableListView
        AbsListView.LayoutParams lp = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 64);

        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(TestActivity.this);
        checkBox.setLayoutParams(lp);
        // Center the text vertically
        checkBox.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT);
        // Set the text starting position
        checkBox.setPadding(36, 0, 0, 0);
        return checkBox;
    }

    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView;
        if(checkBox == null) {
            checkBox = getCheckbox();
        }

        checkBox.setChecked(true);
        checkBox.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());
        return checkBox;
    }

    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groups[groupPosition];
    }

    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.length;
    }

    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
                             ViewGroup parent) {
        android.widget.TextView textView = getGenericView();
        textView.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
        return textView;
    }

    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

layout bits:

```
<org.holoeverywhere.widget.ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandable_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what is the problem with your code , but i suggest you to try changing `CheckBox` to `CheckedTextView`
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckedTextView.html

Comment: the same result, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

May you have to try to declare `CheckBox` Publically.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a possibility, but instead try `checkBox.toggle()`